# SQL Datetime Format Variable Convertion in SAS

Tags: sql, datetime, sas

When I tried to retrieve earliest and latest time stamp by cookie id. I got **1737527710**  instead of **24JAN15:04:06:22**. Can any one help me with the correct way of getting the desired time stamp information?

```
proc sql;
    create table travel.summary as
    select cookie, COUNT(id) as tot_count, SUM(response)as respond_flag, MIN(timestamp)as first_interaction, MAX(timestamp) as last_interaction
    from travel
    group by cookie;
quit;
```

Comment: What is column type of `timestamp`?

Comment: use format as datetime20.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are seeing the unformatted value (SAS datetimes are the number of seconds since 1960-01-01).

You can request that `proc sql` format your variable in the `select` statement like this:

```
min(timestamp) as first_interaction format = datetime.
```